# How to join a table to get description of two fileds of one row from another table

Tags: codeigniter

my tables have userid's like

```
table investigate
-----------------------------------
supervisor   reporter    score
-----------------------------------
 1                2         300
-----------------------------------

user table
----------------------
id             name
----------------------
1                vijay
2                 PHP
----------------------

here i need to join tables and get result as
----------------------------------
supervisor   reporter      score
--------------------------------
vijay         php          300
----------------------------------
```

In mysql how to get result of description from a table for two records from same row on same condition

Comment: you need to do a multi-join in order to grab the data you want. 1 join user-table for your 1st column (supervisor) and 1 more join user-table for your 2nd column (reporter). Be aware that, if a row in table investigate doesn't join both of your values, no result will be returned from mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in Codeigniter. Couldn't test it, but i hope it will help.

```
$this->db->select('user.name as user1, user.name as user2, investigate.score')
$this->db->from('investigate')
$this->db->join('users', 'investigate.supervisor = user1.id AND investigate.reporter = user2.id', 'left')
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL query in your model

`$sql = "SELECT (SELECT name FROM user as t2 WHERE  t2.id = t1.supervisor) as supervisor, (SELECT name FROM user as t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.visitor) as visitor, score FROM  investigate as t1";`

`$this->db->query($sql)->result();`

Hope this works for you...